# Loading data mask manually when using box

Tags: r, dplyr, r-box

I have an R code that I'm changing to use R's [box](https://klmr.me/box/index.html) package.

But I noticed that a function I had no longer has the dataframes columns as variables in the environment, so when I do dplyr's filter I get `object 'verified' not found`.

What's the easiest way to solve this? I want to load the dataframe columns as variables in the function environment.

Simplified version of my code, yes the `verified` column does exist

```
box::use(
  tibble[...],
  dplyr[...],
  lubridate[...],
  r/core[...]
)

myFunction <- function(df){
  df = df %>%
    filter(verified == TRUE)
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: So, ```r/core``` is causing the problem. When you take that line of code out, it works, if you put it back in, you get that error message. Do you need library r/core in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you load `r/core` after `dplyr`, `stats::filter()` is masking `dplyr::filter()`. If you load `r/core` first, it works as intended:

```
box::use(
  r/core[...],
  tibble[...],
  dplyr[...],
  lubridate[...]
)

myFunction <- function(df){
  df = df %>%
    filter(verified == TRUE)
  return(df)
}

dat <- tibble(
  x = 1:2,
  verified = c(F, T)
)

myFunction(dat)
```

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      x verified
  <int> <lgl>   
1     2 TRUE
```

Alternatively, you could specify `dplyr::filter()` in your function.

(Finally, I’m not that familiar with box, but do you really have to explicitly load `r/core` at all?)

Comment: That worked, I didn't realize I was using the wrong filter function. And yes, modules loaded by box don't include r/core, but I didn't need to load it all